# Updating a ContentProvider's underlying SQLite database from internet resource

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a implemented a `ContentProvider` to serve up a list of geographical locations from an underlying SQLite database.

These locations are actually an output from a model and are available online in the form of a simple JSON string; I don't want to keep downloading them every time the app is started, so I want to store them locally in a database and update them at pre-defined intervals (once a day for instance).

My question is, where should I implement the downloading and parsing code? Should it be part of my `ContentProvider` implementation? Or part of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation?

I started to implement it as a public function called `updateSiteList` in my `ContentProvider`, but I don't know how to actually call it (the ContentProvider is usually acessed indirectly via `CursorLoader`)!

I am bit stuck as to how to progress!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this.
The two most common ways I use are :-

1) a custom sync adapter.

2) An intent service.

With option 1 you get the benefit of the Android system handling network connection problems and is the recommended approach by the android Developers

With option 2 you get more control over when the data gets downloaded which may or may not be the best time for the user or the Android System.

Either way the solution is the same. At some point in time you will be making, in a background service, an HTTP get request to a url. when your request completes you will need to heck the status of the response and if appropriate you would then make a call to the content provider to wither insert or update your data accordingly. whichever approach you take this part will be the same.

Some further reading for you.
https://sites.google.com/site/andsamples/concept-of-syncadapter-androidcontentabstractthreadedsyncadapter

Be sure to watch that Google I/O video

Regardless of the approach you take, the code to download json and insert to your content provider could look something like this in an IntentService called from either your sync adapter or from somewhere within your app if not using a sync adapter.

```
public class ServiceInitialiseData extends IntentService {
    static final String TAG = "ServiceSyncData";
    //ACTION should include application package convention, just to show that this can
    //be any string
    public static final String SYNC_COMPLETED_ACTION="com.pjmobile.games.fantasyf1.SyncCompleted";

    public ServiceInitialiseData() {
        super("InitialiseDataService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String sJson;
        try {
            sJson = downloadFromServer("Some parsed url");
            int i, x;
            boolean res = false;
            List <ContentValues> bulkValues = new ArrayList <ContentValues>();
            JSONArray entries;
            try {
                entries = new JSONArray(sJson);
                ContentValues cvEntity = null;
                JSONObject entity;
                x = entries.length();
                for (i=0;i<x;i++){
                    entity = entries.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("some_json_key");
                    bulkValues.add(cvEntity);
                }
            }
            int qCount = getContentResolver().bulkInsert(uri,
            (ContentValues[])bulkValues.toArray(new
                    ContentValues[bulkValues.size()]));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    private String downloadFromServer(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpResponse sJson = getJSONEntityFromURL(this, url);
        return EntityUtils.toString(sJson.getEntity());
    }

    private static HttpResponse getJSONEntityFromURL(Context context, String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpget.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        return response;
    }
```

For the above to work you would have to ode up the bulk insert method of your content provider which could look something like this

```
    @Override
    public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        int numInserted= 0;
//        Util.log_debug_message("@@@@ URI MATCH - " + match);
        switch(match){
            case TEAMS:
                numInserted = insertTeams(db, values);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported uri: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null, false);
        return numInserted;
    }

    private int insertTeams(SQLiteDatabase db, ContentValues[] values) {
        int numInserted = 0;
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
        //standard SQL insert statement, that can be reused
            SQLiteStatement insert = 
                db.compileStatement(INSERT_OR_REPLACE_STRING + TeamModel.TEAM_TABLE_NAME
                        + "(" + TeamModel.COL_SERVER_ID
                        + "," + TeamModel.COL_BONUS_RACE_ID
                        + "," + TeamModel.COL_POINTS
                        + "," + TeamModel.COL_POSITION
                        + "," + TeamModel.COL_TEAM_NAME + ")"
                        +" values " + "(?,?,?,?,?)");

            for (ContentValues value : values){
    //bind the 1-indexed ?'s to the values specified
                insert.bindString(1, value.getAsString(TeamModel.COL_SERVER_ID));
                insert.bindString(2, value.getAsString(TeamModel.COL_BONUS_RACE_ID));
                insert.bindString(3, value.getAsString(TeamModel.COL_POINTS));
                insert.bindString(4, value.getAsString(TeamModel.COL_POSITION));
                insert.bindString(5, value.getAsString(TeamModel.COL_TEAM_NAME));
                insert.execute();
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            numInserted = values.length;
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
        return numInserted;
    }
```

This is not a copy and paste solution. Merely an example stripped out of one of my apps and you should look at each line of code and take great care to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Coding up the sync adapters looks a bit complex - especially the Account side of it. I will try it with the IntentService approach. Thanks again!